# Is this the right word for "gratuitous"?

Tags: word-usage

"Unentgeglich" is a word I can't find in dictionaries but have heard used. I think I have spelled it right. Can it be used to mean something is cost free?

Comment: „unentgeltlich“

Comment: Which meaning of _gratuitous_ are you referring to? Remember there're expressions such as _gratuitous violence_, where it would be better translated as _unnötig_, _unangebracht_, or synonyms along those lines.

Comment: Leo has the following: https://dict.leo.org/ende/?lang=en&search=gratuitous *free of charge, e.g. service  adj.* = `unentgeltlich`, `gratis`, `kostenlos` other meanings as Marakai already said can be `überflüssig`, `unnötig`, `grundlos` or `unbegründet` like in Gratuitous German http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GratuitousGerman

Comment: @Marakai, the OP says "cost free".

Comment: Context please!

Answer (score 6):

*Unentgeltlich* (your spelling is a bit off) is the most high-level expression to say something  is "for free". It is often used by public administration, you nearly never hear it in everyday speech. Usability is also a bit limited because its only use is like in

> Sie erhalten eine unentgeltliche Probepackung

while

> Die Probepackung ist unentgeltlich

is gramatically right, but sounds very odd.

*Kostenlos* is more on the everyday side, means the same.

Both are used exclusively used saying that something does not *cost money*

The third one in the range, is *umsonst*, which *can* mean that something is for free, but has a second meaning of "in vain" or "useless" - The danger with this word is illustrated by

> Meine Schule war kostenlos - Deine anscheinend umsonst

(Could mean both my and your education was for free, but rather targets at the second meaning, saying my education was for free, yours useless)

Despite of this, the last one is the most often used to say something is for free.

Comment: There's also "gratis".

Comment: There's also "kostenfrei", "frei", "nicht kostenpflichtig", "gebühenfrei", "geschenkt", "für nichts", "billig", "ohne Entgelt", "nicht entgeltpflichtig" and maybe a gazillion of other expressions with the same or similar meaning. My answer tries to cover the three most important ones.

Comment: Not to forget _für umme_.

Comment: *für lau* - nicht ganz so nah am sprachlichen Abgrund ;)

Answer (score 3):

"Unentgeltlich" is related to German "gratis", which matches the "old school" meaning of "without compensation expected", but which has little to do with how "gratuitous" is commonly used in the english language today (eg in "gratuitous sex and violence", implying a negative judgement) - which would, depending on context, be best translated by "sinnlos", "überflüssig", "verschwenderisch", "willkürlich".